# TinyMCE on Drupal 7 adding class to <p> instead of <span>

Tags: input-formats, theming, wysiwyg

I have a custom class that I want to be able to add to parts of a sentence using a <span> tag. It's a title field, so I don't want it to be wrapped in a <p> tag. However, TinyMCE insists on wrapping everything in <p>.

I thought configuring my input filter to strip out <p> tags would be a good solution, and everything works on my dev environment, but on the staging environment, the classes are being added to the later-removed <p> tag instead of a <span>.

Using <span> instead of <p> is particularly important because the user needs to be able to add the custom class to single words in the title without including the whole title.

Comment: If I'm reading this right you're saying you've added a text filter to the Title field, but I didn't think that was possible.  In any case, why is it **not** okay to write a style that specifies a `span` inside of a `p`?

Comment: It's not the built-in title field, it's a field called "Rich Title" that I'm using as the page heading as if it were a title. I want to prevent the use of paragraph tags because the field does not contain paragraphs and should never be included in paragraph styling.

Comment: I wonder if it's not TinyMCE adding a `<p>` wrapper and instead the default handling of a Text Field widget type. And in that case maybe you can write a preprocessor like `hook_field_display_alter` or `hook_views_pre_render`to alter the html wrapping around the field.

Comment: It's definitely being added in TinyMCE. It appears in the field when I disable the rich text editor, and if I remove it, it reappears on re-enabling.